# How GroupJoin in C# using LINQ works

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to learn C#, but I can't understand how groupjoin works in the example I'm seeing in the tutorial.

Here the code:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Book[] books = {new Book(1, "Harry Potter", 1), new Book(2, "LOTR", 2), new Book(3, "Divina Commedia", 2),
            new Book(4, "Morgante", 2), new Book(5, "A Study in Scarlet", 1)};

            Owner[] owners = { new Owner(1, "Fabiano"), new Owner(2, "Matteo") };

            //you can also do groupjoin
            var groupjoin = from owner in owners
                            join book in books on
                            owner.Id equals book.OwnerId
                            into ownerGroup
                            select new
                            {
                                Owner = owner.Name,
                                Book = from owner2 in ownerGroup
                                            orderby owner2.Name
                                            select owner2
                            };

            int totalBooks = 0;

            foreach(var ownerGroup in  groupjoin)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine(ownerGroup.Owner);
                foreach(var b in ownerGroup.Book)
                {
                    totalBooks++;
                    Console.WriteLine("* {0}", b.Name);
                }
            }
        }

        internal class Book
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int OwnerId { get; set; }
            public Book(int id, string name, int ownerId)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
                OwnerId = ownerId;
            }
        }

        internal class Owner
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }


            public Owner(int id, string name)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
            }
   
        }

    }
}
```

The code works, meaning that It prints the owner.Name and after that the book.Name for each book that belongs to that owner.

I can't understand the following piece of code

```cs
var groupjoin = 
    from owner in owners
    join book in books on
    owner.Id equals book.OwnerId
    into ownerGroup
    select new
    {
        Owner = owner.Name,
        Book = from owner2 in ownerGroup
                    orderby owner2.Name
                    select owner2
    };
```

I've understood (but correct me if I'm wrong) that the code

```cs
from owner in owners
join book in books on
owner.Id equals book.OwnerId
into ownerGroup
```

saves the result of the join in `ownerGroup` so that `ownerGroup` can be use in another query. But I can't understand how the following piece of code makes the result I get.

```cs
select new
{
    Owner = owner.Name,
    Book = from owner2 in ownerGroup
            orderby owner2.Name
            select owner2
};
```

Can you please explain it to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so first: the name owner2 is very missleading, since the datatype behind that is actually a Book.
So basically what happens is:
In the first part it finds all books that can be joined with the owner its currently looking for (so that would be the first one at that time).
The result of that will be saved to the ownerGroup. Which could be better named, since it is a IEnumerable or to put it very simply (but also a bit TOO simple) a list of the books that were joined.

the select new just means that it will return a type that isnt defined/anonymos.
The Owner = owner.Name just means that itll pick the name of the Owner that it is currently itterating for.

The Book = .... is just you ordering/sorting the compiled book list that is in ownerGroup.

And this will return a object with a Owner Name and a collection of books and then do the same thing again for the next users.

So as a step by step

```
from owner in owners
join book in books on
    owner.Id equals book.OwnerId
    into ownerGroup
```

Can be imagined as: We start to look for all books related to Fabiano and remember that.
So owner is currently Fabiano and ownerGroup is Harry Potter and A Study in Scarlet.

```
select new
{
    Owner = owner.Name,
    Book = from ownedBooks in ownerGroup
        orderby ownedBooks.Name
        select ownedBooks
}
```

Picks out Fabianos name and orders the books alphabetically.
So now it has a result object holding the name and the books.
Then it does the exact same thing for Matteo, and once it has gone through all the users your groupjoin will be a IEnumerable filled with Objects that have a name string attribute and a list of books attribute.

So I think rewriting the query to look like this

```
var groupjoin =
    from owner in owners
    join book in books on
        owner.Id equals book.OwnerId
        into ownedBooks
    select new
    {
        Owner = owner.Name,
        Book = from ownedBook in ownedBooks
               orderby ownedBook.Name
            select ownedBook
    };
```

Will make things quite a lot easier to understand